# How to add new block (without phtml) with links to header content in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, xml, header

[image: example]

What is the correct way to add block with some links and few css classes to header content?
This is correct?

```
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <container name="header.decor" as="headerDecor" label="Header Decor" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-decor">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" htmlClass="link-1" name="link-1">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">link-1</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">link-1</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" htmlClass="link-2" name="link-2">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">link-2</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">link-2</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```

But no class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you "own theme" under `Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`, add the following content.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.custom.links" as="topCustomLinks" template="Magento_Theme::topCustomLinks.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And add the HTML content inside `your_theme/Magento_Theme/templates/topCustomLinks.phtml`

```
<ul>
  <li id="link1">Link 1</li>
  <li id="link2">Link 2</li>
  <li id="link3">Link 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! I change question because need new block without phtml.

Comment: How can we add a signup , wishlist , login  with respective links  in that phtml file...

Answer (score 1):

Add code to your default.xml ,

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
   <container name="header-custom-link" as="header-custom-link" label="Page header-link" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-link content">  
     <referenceBlock name="header.links">
      <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" htmlClass="register" before="-" name="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
        </arguments>
      </block>

      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="wish-link" htmlClass="wishlist" after="register-link">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">My WishList</argument> 
          <argument name="path"  xsi:type="string" translate="false">wishlist/</argument>
        </arguments>
      </block>
     </referenceBlock>
   </container>
 </referenceContainer>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I change question because need new block without phtml.

Comment: @syrgey Please check updated answer.

Comment: This is only one link, but before need creat block or container for custome links...

Comment: You can repeat that same things for as per my answer.

Comment: I mean need same on example foto. You use <referenceBlock name="header.links">. But need creat new div block in header-wrapper. Check please my question.

Comment: You can create new div with container tag.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Created links do not have a class. It is necessary that each link has its own class.

Comment: Entity htmlClass add class for that div , added in register link now it has its class also.

Comment: No, for link this is not works, I update question and show code with htmlClass="link-1", but no class. I use custom link.

Comment: <argument name="path"  xsi:type="string" translate="false">wishlist/</argument> this line use for link.

Comment: I add costom link. You use wishlist. I think if you will try creat custom links. Can't add class for custom links. I don't know why...(